# Get Uploaded Files from NodeJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm trying to retrieve files uploaded to the server with no luck. I'm getting instead: `403 - forbidden` error. (I'm fairly new to NodeJs)

This is NodeJS code:

```
// Get Thumbnail Images
router.param('imageName', function(req, res, next, imageName) {
    req.imageURL = "../uploads/thumbnails/" + imageName;
    return next();
});

router.get('/tn/:imageName', function(req, res) {
    var options = {
        root: __dirname
    };
    res.sendFile(req.imageURL, options);
});
```

this is HTML code:

```
<img ng-src="/tn/{{ card.backImg }}" class="" alt=""/>
```

In addition I tried to add this line in my app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads')));
```

I'm not sure what are the best practices for such situation (all users access to uploaded images). So would you please provide a general explanation as well about public folders, static and best practices.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the source code below is able to work with your case:

```
app.get('/tn/:imageName', function(req ,res) {
    var path = require('path');
    var file = path.join(__dirname, "/../uploads/thumbnails/" , req.params.imageName);
    res.sendFile(file);
});
```

Note: I am using ExpressJS 4.0